# Dialogflow - How to re-prompt an end-user if the input is not valid whilst calling a context?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot, prompt, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Inline Editor (Node.js)

I am building a chatbot where the Bot asks the end-user to give his/her availability date (format: 12 Dec 2020). If the end-user inputs a date before today's date, I want my bot to give a prompt other than the one which is already in my context.

Currently, my code is triggering the context again which is asking the user for the availability date. There is 'Date1' parameter defined in the specific intent which is 'required' and with a single prompt.

How should I provide a custom re-prompt if the 'IF' statement satisfies and then store the input in the same parameter i.e. Date1?

Code Snippet:

```
if(Date4<currentDate){ //Date4 is the availability date //If the Date4 is less than currentDate then the Date intent will be recalled with the prompt mentioned at the bottom.
    agent.context.set({
        'name': 'Date123-followup',
        'lifespan': 1
        
    });
    agent.add('Please provide a valid Date, which is after today.');//the custom prompt
}
```

Ask for more details if needed.

Flow of the Dialog:

**Bot**: Please provide your availability date?

**User**: 1 Jan 2019

*'Current Response which is in the prompt of my intent'*

**Bot**: Please provide your availability date?

*'Required Response: This is what the bot should ask'*

**Bot**: Please provide a valid Date, which is after today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setFollowupEvent` method with an agent object. That will basically trigger any intent you just need to add this event in the intent.

```
agent.setFollowupEvent({ name: 'deliveryEvent', parameters: {} }); // parameters are any data that you want to pass to next conversation.
```

You can set an event in any intent using event option: This way you can trigger this intent from anywhere just take care of context using parameters.
[image]